# codes composed of six uppercase English characters, at least two characters are different between any two codes, how many codes can be generated?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, coding-theory

**Generate a set of codes composed of six uppercase English characters, requiring at least two characters of same position are different between any two codes, how many codes can be generated at most?**

such as

> ['AAAAAA','AAAABB','AAAACC'...]

I have tried exhausive the results, but the code is too slow， or how to optimize the code

````
arrs = []
totalLen = 0
def isValid(t):
  for arr in arrs:
    equalCount = 0
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
      if arr[i] == t[i]:
        if equalCount == len(arr) - 2:
          return False
        else:
          equalCount += 1
  return True
hex = 'Z'
for a in range(ord('A'), ord(hex) + 1):
  for b in range(ord('A'), ord(hex) + 1):
    for c in range(ord('A'), ord(hex) + 1):
      for d in range(ord('A'), ord(hex) + 1):
        for e in range(ord('A'), ord(hex) + 1):
          for f in range(ord('A'), ord(hex) + 1):
            t = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
            if isValid(t):
              arrs.append(t)
              totalLen += 1
              print('    ' + ''.join(chr(ch) for ch in t))
        print('  ' + chr(a) + chr(b) + chr(c) + chr(d) + ' :' + str(len(arrs)))
      print(chr(a) + chr(b) + chr(c) + ' :' + str(len(arrs)))

print(len(arrs))
```
````

Comment: You should experiment with 3 or 4 letter words, over a 6 letter alphabet, instead.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks for comment, I have tried 2 and 3 and 4 letters, the results is 26, 556 and 14408,  556 = (26 - 2) * (26 - 2) - 20, I can't sum up other rules. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I know the answer, and your 556 is wrong, and I don't know how to craft a non-cheating hint.  Maybe if you redid with a 4 letter alphabet, with 3-long words, and printed out your arrs[] array, you could see what you are missing.